# Grunt uncss in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, gruntjs, uncss

I am trying to run grunt uncss in my WordPress custom theme. Below is my configuration file `gruntfile.js`. When I run `grunt` command, I get error

```
 Running "uncss:dist" (uncss) task
 Error: Could not load script: "file:///D:/www/website-wp/wp-content/themes/theme2021/%3C?=get_template_directory_uri()?%3E/assets/js/require.js"
```

Above, I have used `get_template_directory_uri()` wordpress function to get the path to current theme but grunt cannot detect this PHP function as dynamic. So, how can I make this grunt config in `gruntfile.js` to make require.js file to see with correct path.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Below is my gruntfile.js inside theme directory.

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    exec: {
      get_grunt_sitemap: {
         command: 'curl --silent --output sitemap.json http://localhost/website-wp/?show_sitemap'
      }
    },
    uncss: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          ignore: [/\w\.in/,
                    ".fade",
                    ".collapse",
                    ".collapsing",
                    /(#|\.)navbar(\-[a-zA-Z]+)?/,
                    /(#|\.)dropdown(\-[a-zA-Z]+)?/,
                    /(#|\.)(open)/,
                    ".modal",
                    ".modal.fade.in",
                    ".modal-dialog",
                    ".modal-document",
                    ".modal-scrollbar-measure",
                    ".modal-backdrop.fade",
                    ".modal-backdrop.in",
                    ".modal.fade.modal-dialog",
                    ".modal.in.modal-dialog",
                    ".modal-open",
                    ".in",
                    ".modal-backdrop",
                    /expanded/,/js/,/wp-/,/align/,/admin-bar/],
            stylesheets  : ['/dist/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', 'style.css','/css/minified/main.css','/css/minified/media.css'],
            ignoreSheets : [/fonts.googleapis/,/js.hsforms.net/,/require.js/],
            // urls         : [], //Overwritten in load_sitemap_and_uncss task
          },
        // files: {
        //   'assets/compiled/style.css': ['http://localhost/website-wp/']
        // },
         files: {
          'style.clean.css': ['**/*.php']
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-uncss');
 

  grunt.registerTask('load_sitemap_json', function() {
    var sitemap_urls = grunt.file.readJSON('./sitemap.json');
    grunt.config.set('uncss.dist.options.urls', sitemap_urls);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('deploy',
  ['exec:get_grunt_sitemap','load_sitemap_json','uncss:dist']);
   
  

  grunt.registerTask('default', 'uncss');
}
```

Also, I am using `get_template_directory_uri()` in footer.php file in theme directory.

Comment: Can you provide us the configuration file and the code where you have used `get_template_directory_uri()`? Because for me it just looks like you have used the php function in your grunftile / config.

Comment: @Hoargarth I have updated the question. Please find update section for gruntfile.js and `get_template_directory_uri() ` is in footer.php file

Answer (score 1):

I would say, the way you are trying to do does not work.

grunt:uncss is reading your files but does not execute them. Also, if it detects any other file url, it will check this as well.

In your case, you dynamically added require.js to your footer, but grunt:uncss does not know anything about PHP and therefore does not execute the `get_template_directory_uri()`. The resulting problem is, that uncss is grying to find fhe file at location in your error.

I'm not sure if uncss is also reading your function.php, if not you could register and enqueue your require.js there and try it again.

Here's an answer to a similar Problem, with same conclusion that uncss does not work with dynamic PHP files.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35583623/9184970

Also the answer suggests to generate html first and the run uncss, with a specific tutorial for Wordpress here https://gladdy.uk/blog/2014/04/13/using-uncss-and-grunt-uncss-with-wordpress/

Comment: including require.js from function.php didnot worked as well as it tried parsing all the PHP library file as well. Lastly I tried removing `'**/*.php'` and replaced with `'**/*.html'`. Now grunt ran without issue but the design broke. When I saw, all the necessary class css are not generating. Any help is greatly appriciated.

Comment: After investigation further. I found that the bootstrap uses source map file to load various css. But after running grunt-uncss, the source map file css are not included in final css file. Any idea how to include source map file also in grunt config?